# how to bind value to angular material Auto Complete in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7

Hi Am using angular material Auto complete component in my angualr7 app and am figuring out how to bind a value from api response to it. Can any one provide solution to overcome this issue ?

## HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="templateId" name="templateId" #templateId="ngModel" placeholder="Template" matInput
        [matAutocomplete]="auto" aria-label="Number" (keyup)="filter($event)">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onTemplateChange($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let temp of filtered" [value]="temp">
            {{temp.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

## Ts:

```
onTripTemplateChange($event) {
        this.templateId = $event.temp.name;
}
```

1. I need to make value selected by default when i open component
2. When i change option from auto complete list i need to change the selected value

Please let me know the soultion..

Comment: You should read the [excellent official docs](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples) for Angular Material, with examples.

Comment: Yep, already gone through it but those  examples were reactive forms binding but not template driven  forms ..

Answer (score -1):

From the original angular material autocomplete documentation. It is visible to set the value for autocomplete you have to set the value for input.

The original documentation is available here: https://v7.material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

The sample app is also available on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/angular/egaebogmkaa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.ts

This sample app shows only the basic autocomplete scenario but if you set in the .ts a value for input it will select it. Eg.

```
 myControl = new FormControl('One');
```

Comment: Any examples on template driven forms ?